# Looping through columns SQL to select multiple years

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have GDP data for 1960 - 2020, each year is stored as a column.
In order to unpivot the columns, do I have to hard code all year(columns)?

For example

| country name | 1960 | 1961 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | 200 | 400 |
| CANADA | 300 | 400 |

Desired(unpivot)

| countryname | value | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | 200 | 1960 |
| US | 400 | 1961 |
| CANADA | 300 | 1960 |
| CANADA | 400 | 1961 |

But doing this for 1960- 2020, is it necessary to state each year columns in my unpivot statement?

I'm attempting to use dynamic query and at a very starting point, I have

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @year INT = 1960


SET @DynamicSQL = 'SELECT GDP.[' + CAST(@year AS VARCHAR(10)) +'] FROM GDP'


EXEC(@DynamicSQL)
```

But how can I increment 1 year and add the list of years in one SET statement?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a syntax error in your query. Please provide a [mre] including sample data, desired results and your attempt.

Comment: Have you tried to use [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) ?

Comment: Need to see at least some of the table data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach which will dynamically UNPIVOT your data without actually using Dynamic SQL

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1d0e109e710fc2eda8776e5dde8ff77f)**

```
Select A.[country name]
      ,B.*
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select [Key]
                      ,Value
                 From OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )) 
                 Where [Key] not in ('country name','OtherColums','ToExclude')
             ) B
```

**Results**

```
country name    Key     Value
US              1960    200
US              1961    400
CANADA          1960    300
CANADA          1961    400
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're mainly asking about how to loop through the years. The code below should do it. All that's left would be to use this in conjunction with the UNPIVOT statement to fully solve the problem. You can find a neat example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @yearStart INT = 1960
DECLARE @yearEnd INT = 2020
DECLARE @yearIterator INT = @yearStart
DECLARE @fieldPrefix String = 'GDP.[' --where GDP is the table you want to UNPIVOT
DECLARE @fieldSuffix String = ']'

SET @DynamicSQL = 'SELECT ' + @fieldPrefix 

while 1=1
begin

   SET @DynamicSQL = @DynamicSQL + @yearIterator + @fieldSuffix

   if @yearIterator < @yearEnd
   begin

      SET @DynamicSQL = @DynamicSQL + ', '

   end 

   SET @yearIterator = @yearIterator + 1

   if @yearIterator > @yearEnd
   begin

      SET @DynamicSQL = @DynamicSQL + ' FROM GDP'
      break

   end 

end 

EXEC(@DynamicSQL)
```